# Действительно ли va_list переносимый?

Tags: c++, c

В [документации от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/va-arg-va-copy-va-end-va-start?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) заявлено, что `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end` являются переносимыми макросами, однако не понятно, как это может быть реализовано, если параметры функции во многих архитектурах передаются в первую очередь через регистры, а затем через стек. Получается, реализация этих макросов должна контролировать как используемое ABI, так и соглашение о вызовах. Если первое явно задаётся компилятором, то используемое соглашение о вызовах определить внутри функции, вроде бы, невозможно.

Даже если это и можно определить, то как на уровне языка C получить доступ к регистрам, содержащим параметры?

Также сказано:

> If `prev_param` is declared with the `register` storage class, the macro's behavior is undefined.

Эту формулировку не понимаю. Насколько мне известно, объявлять функции таким образом не допускается - иначе мы предписываем компилятору нарушить соглашение о вызовах:

```
int func(register int first, ...);
```

Если же имелось в виду следующее

```
int func(int first, ...);
int main()
{
    register int a = 3;
    func(1, a);
}
```

то разве значение `3` из переменной `a` не переместится туда, куда предусмотрено соглашением о вызовах?

Comment: *"не понятно, как это может быть реализовано"* Известно как, на `#ifdef`-ах. Это все равно что спросить как `printf` может быть переносимым, ведь на каждой ОС системные вызовы для печати свои.

Comment: Там же ясно напиcано `prev_param - Parameter that precedes the first optional argument.` *"объявлять функции таким образом не допускается"* - допускается, на соглашение о вызовах оно никак не влияет

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, каким образом `#ifdef` может определить, через регистр передан параметр, или через стек? И как потом извлечёт его из регистра?

Comment: @user7860670, если мы используем соглашение, которое все параметры передаёт через стек, то как поведёт себя ключевое слово `register` в объявлении функции?

Comment: По моему cdecl на 64 битной архитектуре говорит о том что все параметры передаются через регистры, если это возможно

Comment: @maestro *"каким образом #ifdef может определить"* А посмотрите, как у вас в компиляторе это сделано. Скорее всего есть какие-то макросы, по которым можно определить текущую архитектуру. Или еще вариант - вся эта магия встроена напрямую в компилятор, надо смотреть.

Comment: Ну в С++ это ключевое слово совсем ничего не делает. В С компилятор сделает по своему усмотрению. `register` практически ни к чему не обязывает, типа как `inline`.

Comment: @user7860670 Занудство: теперь оно [вызывает ошибку](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан неверно.

Не "в документации от MS", и не "переносимость", а - **СТАНДАРТ**.

А уж как разработчики того или иного компилятора его реализуют - это их, разработчиков, проблемы.

Что касается `register` - это слово из лексикона С++ исключено :)

Comment: нет, слово register  не исключено. Оно просто зарезервировано и сейчас ничего не значит

Comment: Хорошо, исключено как влияющее на что-либо. Есть оно или нет - это ничего не меняет.

Comment: @Mikhailo Не, оно теперь вызывает ошибку компиляции. Но использовать его как идентификатор все равно нельзя.

Comment: Вобщем, договаривайтесь сами, как оно там по вашим стандартам :) Я для себя его считаю просто запрещенным к употреблению...

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто: параметры в функции с переменным количеством аргументов всегда передаются через блоки памяти, это единственный способ не быть ограниченным в количестве таких параметров сверху количеством доступных регистров, используемых для передачи параметров в обычные функции.
Блоки памяти могут быть аллоцированы на стеке (наиболее распространённый вариант), но ничто не мешает откусить память в куче или вообще организовать передачу параметров в виде списка или любого другого упорядоченного контейнера.

Функции с переменным количеством аргументов - зло и источник боли.

Comment: ох, боюсь этот ответ заминусуют...

Comment: Как способ решения это звучит логично. В каких именно компиляторах реализован этот принцип?

Comment: @KoVadim - а не жалко. Вопрос maestro достоин ответа, большинство же не спрашивает, а использует элементы среды или языка как некоторую необсуждаемую данность. maestro - не совсем понимаю, о каком принципе вы здесь спрашиваете. Если о возможности по-разному организовывать память под список параметров, то если честно, то кроме массива на стэке я за свою практику работы с C/C++ ничего не видел.